# How do I derive the generala formula? Does anyone know a way of thinking ot apply this to other problems?

Tags: probability, games

[image]

The textbook said that it would be easy to derive the general formula. Is there a certain way of thinking that I am not seeing? I understand that the equation is doing (whole - piece) / whole.

The question is using a dart board as an example. There are 5 regions to hit. The distance between regions is r/5

Comment: The area of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2.$  Thus, the area of a ring of outer radius $R$ and inner radius $r$ is $\pi R^2 - \pi r^2.$ The rest is purely algebra.

Comment: My confusion lies in how he went from 1-(4/5)^2 to the generalized form of the equation. I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: You need to look at the figure because it will indicate how to determine $R$ and $r$ in terms of $i.$

Comment: I think this question doesn't ask for a solution as described in the `self-study` explanation. It shares the solution and asks to understand it. But, the way it is asked is uncomfortable and unaesthetic because it just provides a bad screen-shot, instead of writing the question/answer in Latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each point, you need to hit the region between the following inner and outer radii:
$$\begin{align}&\text{Points}&\text{OutR, InR}\\&1 \text{ point}\rightarrow &5r/5, 4r/5\\&2 \text{ points}\rightarrow&4r/5,3r/5\\&3 \text{ points}\rightarrow&3r/5,2r/5\\&4 \text{ points}\rightarrow&2r/5,r/5\\&5 \text{ points}\rightarrow&r/5,0\end{align}$$

These outer and inner radii are nothing but $(6-i)r/5$ and $(5-i)r/5$, which makes up the numerator in your first formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now that I kept thinking of outer R as remaining constant R.